# Contact form doesn't accept Greek characters

Tags: javascript, validation, email, contact-form

When someone put Greek characters in the NAME field on SEND the contact form returns with an error report.
So, how do I edit my validation form to accept Greek characters in both NAME & MESSAGE fields?

```
function validation() {
var contactname = document.forms["contactfrm"]["name"].value;
var name_exp = /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/;
if (contactname == '') {
swal("You forgot your name...", " ", "warning");
document.forms["contactfrm"]["name"].focus();
return false;
} else if (!contactname.match(name_exp)) {
swal("Invalid name...", " ", "error");
document.forms["contactfrm"]["name"].focus();
return false;
} 
var email = document.forms["contactfrm"]["email"].value; 
//var email_exp = /^[A-Za-z0-9\.-_\$]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
var email_exp = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
if (email == '') {
swal("You forgot to enter your email...", " ", "warning");
document.forms["contactfrm"]["email"].focus();
return false;
} else if (!email.match(email_exp)) {
swal("Your email address is invalid...", " ", "error");
document.forms["contactfrm"]["email"].focus();
return false;
}
var message = document.forms["contactfrm"]["comments"].value;  
if (message == '') {
swal("No empty messages, please...", "warning");
document.forms["contactfrm"]["comments"].focus();
return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing the name expression to:

```
name_exp=/^[A-ZA-zΑ-Ωα-ωίϊΐάέήόύϋΰώΆΈΉΌΏΎΫ\s]+$/;
```

and email expression to:

```
//var email_exp=/^[A-Za-z0-9\.-_\$]+@[A-Za-z]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/;
var email_exp=/^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
```